# Who's getting the contribution between different levels of relation?

Tags: webform-civicrm, contributions

I (still & again) have a complex webform with individual related to sub-types of organization ([more information here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35418/multiple-of-same-memberships-with-webfom-reloaded)) and even though the memberships goes to organization, the individual is getting the contribution but not the concerned organization.

How can I set it so that the organization ("the real member") is also getting both membership and contribution?

Regards,

Guillaume

[EDIT 1]: "Soft Credit To" assigns the contribution to the sub-type contacts but it's a kind of trick and not exactly what I want.

Comment: on the webform civicrm tab, you have several contacts and you have a membership and a contribution tab. on the membership tab, which of your contacts is the membership set to, and is that the same on the contribution tab?

Comment: In the webform civicrm tab /membership tab, I have Memberships for the Organization sub-type 1 (entreprise) for the 5 contacts with a Membership Fee. Owner gets no membership.

In the webform civicrm tab /contribution tab, I only have one contribution page but I don't see how to set it to a specific contact. Should I set "Soft Credit To" the proper contacts?